# Url is being hashed

Tags: views

I have this page: http://devbe.webhosting.be/catalogus

At the top of the page you will see some links, the URL behing the link is http://devbe.webhosting.be/catalogus/Babykamer for instance...

Whenever I click on the first item for instance, the URL changes not to /babykamer but to  /catalogus#filter%5Bcategory%5D=.babykamer

This function is originally part of my theme, I want to know how I can disable this URL hash function...

It must be somewhere in one of the JS files, but I cannot find it.

Many thanks!
Bjorn

Comment: The strange thing is that with the term 'Bureau' (second term in the list), all works as expected. So I assume the other terms must be hard coded somewhere to apply this URL hashing...

Comment: I found the solution, there was a redirect stored in the DB but it was nearly impossible to find it as a search for the term 'babykamer' in the redirect module didn't provide the right result... I had to search for term/

Comment: Dag (oeps: "hi") Bjorn, I suggest you rework your 2 comments like so: (1) integrate your first comment in your question (via an extra edit) and (2) create your own answer in which you include what is in your 2nd comment. Then delete both comments, and "mark" your own answer as accepted. Just trying to get you going on this site, ok?